# Cypress entering text into a dynamic ID search box

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

How to use dynamic ID in automation testing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aria-label` for this like:

```js
cy.get('input[aria-label="main-search-box-ui-lib-container"]').type('text')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make your test more stable if you could add a `data-testid` to your `input`. If not, you use an attribute unique to the input it would really depend on your pages' DOM.

Some possibilities.

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder]')
cy.get('input[autocomplete]')
cy.get('input[data-key]')
cy.get('input[value]')
// you can combine the above to make them more unique
```